# Linq to SQL - Refresh changes after failed remove

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

So this is my code

```
var r = (from c in db.veClientes where c.Codigo.Equals(cod) select c).FirstOrDefault();
db.veClientes.DeleteOnSubmit(r);
try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch
{
    r.DeBaja = 'S';
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Basically I get a client, try to delete it, if I cant I have to update the client and set a field to 'S'.
The problem is the second submitChanges still wants to perform the delete, and fails again, I cannot delete because of relationships, so I just disable the item. 
How can I refresh the changes so I just update instead of deleting AND updating?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:-

```
var r = (from c in db.veClientes where c.Codigo.Equals(cod) select c).FirstOrDefault();
try
{
    r.DeBaja = "S";
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: Smart, first update then delete. It's another step but in my app that doesn't matter at all. Not a solution but it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch
{
    db.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues, r);
    r.DeBaja = 'S';
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Nope, it still tries to remove the entity and fails.